# H2 Database driver not found?

Tags: jsp, h2

I have gone through other posts stating "Driver not found in H2 database" none of them helped me. I'm using H2 embedded database with JSP in netbeans
I've included the H2 JAR file in my project directory and my code is:

```
<%
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    String u=session.getAttribute("userid").toString();
    String p=session.getAttribute("password").toString();
    String db=session.getAttribute("database").toString();
    Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection(db,u,p);
    Statement s=c.createStatement();
%>
```

I'm getting the error as:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable
>   driver found for mydatabase.

So what am I wrong with??

Comment: How are you running the JSP file? have you included the H2 jar file in war build file?

Comment: H2 JAR file must be either in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your **deployed** web application, or in the library folder of your servlet container (`$CATALINA_HOME/lib` in case you use Tomcat).